# Why not LinearClassifer when RidgeClassifier works?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, machine-learning-model

Recently I came across this model called **RidgeClassifier**,
It coverts the predicted value (y) to {-1,1} and then uses the Ridge Regression. During prediction if the value of y is < 0 then it is predicted as -1 and
if the value of y is > 0 then it is predicted as +1.

So, when **RidgeClassifier** works well for pretty well for some datasets, Why dont/cant we have something called **LinearClassifer** which can use LinearRegression during training and the same model for prediction?

Comment: In other words, why can't we use a regression model for a classification task, by just pretending the dependent variable is continuous?

Comment: What stops you from doing this method without a ridge regression penalty?

Comment: I think this [why no classification with regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22381/why-not-approach-classification-through-regression) explains that....? Why cant we make the same argument for RidgeClassifier, expecting it does not work, But then how does it work @Dave

Answer (score 1):

My stance aligns with what Frank Harrell wrote in the link you gave, so I will not defend the methodology you propose; I am a fan of working with probability outputs. However, nothing stops you from doing the modeling with an OLS regression. After all, the parameters in ridge regression are (typically) calculated as $\hat\beta_{ridge} = (X^TX +\lambda I_{p\times p})^{-1}X^Ty$. If you do the special case of this where $\lambda = 0$, you get the usual OLS equation.

If you are determined to predict on a continuum and then convert to discrete classes, linear regression is just as viable as ridge regression.

**Example in R**

```
set.seed(2021)
N <- 100
x <- runif(N,-2, 2)
z <- x
pr <- 1/(1 + exp(-z))
y <- rbinom(N, 1, pr) 
y_alt <- 2*y - 1 # convert to +/- 1
L <- lm(y_alt ~ x)
preds <- predict(L)
```

Now take `preds > 0` as `y_alt = +1` and `preds < 0` as `y_alt = -1`.